# Google sign in failed Firease authentication android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have created an app and today uploaded to alpha test track. But I'm facing some issues. I have implemented firebase authentication(Google sign in). After uploading app to play store google sign in failed (Authentication is working fine before uploading app on play store).

Here is the code (Google sign in)

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });

private void signIn() {

        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignIn(task);
        }

    }

    private void handleSignIn(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {

        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            Toast.makeText(this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.e("TAG_failure", "Google sign in failed");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {

        loadingDialog.show();

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            loadingDialog.dismiss();
                            Log.d("TAG_S", "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            //firebaseDataHandler();
                            queryData();
                            authLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.e("TAG_F", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            //updateUI(null);
                            loadingDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Here is the **build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
```

And also the Google in app purchase is not working after uploading app to play console

In **proguard-rules.pro** I added this line

```
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**
```

I also added Billing permission but I don't know why is this not working

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Is there any obfuscating issue I don't know.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you mean "failed"? If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Failed means I'm using try/catch block, in catch block I add a toast "Failed" u can check

Comment: I don't know why is this happening, this is working fine but after uploading app to play store google sign in is not working

Comment: You have an error in the authentication. Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I added these lines and the issue solved

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontnote com.google.**

-keep class persistence.** {
  *;
}

-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**
```